# hedge trimmers Ryobi powr LT2

Tags: tools, hedge

every year I struggle like a donkey to start my hedge trimmer for the first time. I wonder what could be causing this because once started I no longer have any problems.
the candle
the gasoline oil mixture
I don't know

However, I follow the instructions in the photo below to the letter

how to test the spark plug? any clue to help me?
Thanks

[image: ryobi notice]

Comment: Have you considered just shifting to a battery operated one?  Charge battery, pull trigger and you go.  No servicing, no emissions.  I switched from an expensive Stihl trimmer to a cheap 48v electric one years ago and never looked back.

Comment: thanks for your suggest @davidgo ; I'm always affraid by battery-based tools because of autonomy duration but here for a trimmer this fear could be excluded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you do in the fall before putting it away?

If you don't run stabilized fuel through it, or drain every drop of fuel out of it, there will usually be problems from gas/petrol sitting over the winter. If you don't put stabilizer in the gas/petrol, or use it an another compatible peice of winter equipment, the gas/petrol that sat all winter in the gas/petrol can isn't very good either. Fresh fuel mix and a dose of carburetor cleaner might help. Starting it every month (whether you use it or not) and running until it's fully warmed up **will** help. Letting it sit for several months is generally not good. If you are looking ahead several months to local spring, go start the thing **now.**

Testing spark plugs is moderately awkward. If you suspect the plug, get a new one and try it, but if it's fine until Fall once started once in Spring, it's not the plug. To test the plug and ignition system you need to get the plug out, but keep it in contact with the engine metal while you pull the cord, preferably with no fuel in the machine, and look for a spark. Or simply check the appearance and gap of the plug, as the awkwardness and tendency to get annoyingly shocked while attempting to test the plug is tiresome.

Comment: Well your detailed answer is amazing! You're correct, I let old petrol sitting in it all over the winter and without running it for months! I'll follow your advice to avoid to struggle next time. Huge thanks. I'll accept this answer 